# Compile Error CS0305

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# programming and have hit a snag I cannot get past.

I'm getting this compile error:

> CS0305: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' reuires 1 type arguments

with this code;

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car c = new Car();
            c.PetName = "Frank";
            c.Speed = 55;
            c.colour = "Green";

            Console.WriteLine("Name = : {0}", c.PetName);
            c.DisplayStats();

            Garage carLot = new Garage();

            // Hand over each car in the collection
            foreach (Car c in carLot)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is going {1} MPH",
                    c.PetName, c.CurrentSpeed);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        class Car
        {
            //Automatic Properties
            public string PetName { get; set; }
            public int Speed { get; set; }
            public string colour { get; set; }

            public void DisplayStats()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Car Name: {0}", PetName);
                Console.WriteLine("Speed: {0}", Speed);
                Console.WriteLine("Color: {0}", colour);
            }
        }

        public class Garage
        {
            private Car[] CarArray = new Car[4];

            // Fill with some car objects on startup.
            public Garage()
            {
                carArray[0] = new Car("Rusty", 30);
                carArray[1] = new Car("Clunker", 55);
                carArray[2] = new Car("Zippy", 30);
                carArray[3] = new Car("Fred", 30);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (Car c in carArray)
            {
                yield return c;
            }
        }

    }
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Something's missing from that code: a class must implement the `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` interface to be used in a `foreach` statement. I don't see that in the Garage class.

Comment: @Etienne, it's more intuitive for it to implement one of those interfaces, *but it is not required.* Having a suitable `GetEnumerator` method is sufficient. See section 8.8.4 of the C# language specification if interested.

Comment: @Anthony Interesting, didn't know about that. Then again, there's no `GetEnumerator` method in the `Garage` class.

Answer (score 6):

There are two variants of `IEnumerable`, the generic one (which is in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace) accepts a type argument which specified the types of objects that the enumerable contains.  The other one (contained in the `System.Collections` namespace) has no type argument and so exposes the type `object` - you appear to be declaring / using the non-generic variant, however are not using the `System.Collections` namespace.

I think the quick way to fix your particular compile error is to put the following at the top of your source code file:

```
using System.Collections;
```

Alternatively you can instead use the Generic version (which you should try to do wherever possible as it is type safe) by specifying type parameters when you declare `IEnumerable`, like this:

```
 IEnumerable<Car>
 IEnumerator<Car>
```

You might also want to read [An Introduction to C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You also seem to have a few more errors than that, but these seem like they might be from problems copying and pasting the source (specifically `Garage` does not implement `IEnumerable`, either the generic or non-generic version, and `GetEnumerator` is on the `Program` class, not the `Garage` class).

Answer (score 1):

You have more errors than just that. But specifically for that error, you're looping over `Garage` in a `foreach`, but that class does not expose an enumerator, mainly because the method `GetEnumerator` is actually outside of the class. Move the method inside `Garage` and then you'll be able to get all the way to scene of the next crash.

Actually, for that error, you need `using System.Collections;` and *then* you need to move the `GetEnumerator` method. Like I said, you have tons of errors in this code.

Comment: @Tony, We're computer programmers... we only exist to change the error messages.

Comment: THank you that has helped alot

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of typos.  As others have said, your specific answer is you need to add ": IEnumerable" to your class Garage statement.

Here is the code fixed enough to compile cleanly:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Car c = new Car ("Frank", 55);
        c.colour = "Green";

        Console.WriteLine ("Name = : {0}", c.PetName);
        c.DisplayStats ();

        Garage carLot = new Garage ();

        // Hand over each car in the collection
        foreach (Car ch in carLot) {
            Console.WriteLine ("{0} is going {1} MPH", ch.PetName, ch.Speed);
        }

        Console.ReadLine ();
    }

    class Car
    {
        //Automatic Properties
        public string PetName { get; set; }
        public int Speed { get; set; }
        public string colour { get; set; }

        public void DisplayStats ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Car Name: {0}", PetName);
            Console.WriteLine ("Speed: {0}", Speed);
            Console.WriteLine ("Color: {0}", colour);
        }

        public Car(string petname, int speed) { PetName = petname; Speed = speed; }
    }

    public class Garage : IEnumerable
    {
        private Car[] carArray = new Car[4];

        // Fill with some car objects on startup.
        public Garage ()
        {
            carArray[0] = new Car ("Rusty", 30);
            carArray[1] = new Car ("Clunker", 55);
            carArray[2] = new Car ("Zippy", 30);
            carArray[3] = new Car ("Fred", 30);
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator ()
        {
            foreach (Car c in carArray) {
                yield return c;
            }
        }

    }

}
```